# bash, remove characters between a path twice in a line

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I have to clean a file (xml), like

```
...
<MSGD:abc xmlns:MSGD="urn:def:xsd:abc.0.0.0">
<HTRT:xyz>00000000</HTRT:xyz>
...
```

to

```
<abc xmlns:MSGD="urn:def:xsd:abc.0.0.0">
<xyz>00000000</xyz>
```

I searched and tried with sed, for i.e. `sed -e 's/<.*:/</g' test.xml` but didn't find the right way

```
<abc.0.0.0">
<xyz>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Be careful if you're removing the XML namespace prefixes from an XML file. It changes the meaning of the element/attribute names. Conflicts are possible if an element exists in both namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to remove the upper case text in the name of XML tags if it happens in the beginning of the name and up to `:`.

In just one command:

```
$ sed -r 's#(</?)[A-Z]*:#\1#g' file
<abc xmlns:MSGD="urn:def:xsd:abc.0.0.0">
<xyz>00000000</xyz>
```

- `(</?)[A-Z]*:` look for `<` + optional `/` + set of capital letters + `:` and catch the first block (`<` + optional `/`).
- `\1` replace with the catched group
- `g` multiple times

Alternatively, in two steps:

```
sed -e 's#<[A-Z]*:#<#' -e 's#</[A-Z]*:#</#' file
```

- `-e` allows you to execute two commands in the same `sed` invocation.
- `s/<[A-Z]*:/</` looks for `<` + capital letters and replaces it with just `<`.
- `s#</[A-Z]*#</#` looks for `</` + capital letters and replaces it with just `<`.

Comment: There were some fixes I had to do. Check the update I did a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed 's/<[^ >]*:/</g' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, can you explain shortly why? :)

Comment: It is matching "`<`, anything but not space or `>`, `:`" and replaces it with a single `<`. That matches the XML namespace prefixes.

Comment: Thanks. @ab Please close this question by accepting answer if you think it helped you.

Comment: Thank you, so the "not space or >" is what cause the different behaviour, it is like an "edge" so we have two string replaced instead of one as in my first attempt

Comment: Remember in your case its greedy .*: it will match everything till last ":" i..e colon and that's what i tried to exclude.

Comment: Just for accuracy, little "problem" with the / that was removed, <xyz>00000000<xyz>

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's#<\([^:>]*\):\(.*\)\(/\1\)#<\2#;t
     s#<[^:>]*:#<#' YourFile
```

posix version (so `--posix`on GNU sed)

test first if there is a remaining "prefix" in a close tag, if not, only try a prefix remove

Comment: Tnak you, just a litte problem <IdCBISndrf>00000000<:IdCBISndrf> but don't worry :)

Comment: correction made (add exclusion of `>` in first search pattern